# Is there a shorter way or a pythonic way to generate custom html that follows a pattern using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am constructing HTML as part of a bigger project. The construction works, no issues with that. However I fear that the code is too verbose or that I am not using the full power of BeautifulSoup.

For Example: I am generating a `div` tag of class `editorial` that wraps a `div` of class `editorial-title`, `editorial-image`, `editorial-subtitle`, `editorial-article` in that order.

Sample HTML-

```html
<div class="editorial">
    <div class="editorial-title">Hello</div>
    <div class="editorial-image"><img src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/collie-border/n02106166_2595.jpg"></div>
    <div class="editorial-subtitle">world</div>
    <div class="editorial-article">Yeah. But Parasite? It should have been Gone with the Wind!</div>
</div>
```

Here is the long code that works for small demo version of what I am trying to do -

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

title = "Hello"
subtitle = "world"
image_url = "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/collie-border/n02106166_2595.jpg"
article = "But Parasite? It should have been Gone with the Wind!"

editorial_container = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')
editorial_container_soup = editorial_container.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "editorial"})

editorial_soup = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

editorial_title = editorial_soup.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "editorial-title"})
editorial_image = editorial_soup.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "editorial-image"})
image = editorial_soup.new_tag('img', src=image_url)
editorial_subtitle = editorial_soup.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "editorial-subtitle"})
editorial_article = editorial_soup.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "editorial-article"})

editorial_title.append(title)
editorial_image.append(image)
editorial_subtitle.append(subtitle)
editorial_article.append(article)

editorial_soup.append(editorial_title)
editorial_soup.append(editorial_image)
editorial_soup.append(editorial_subtitle)
editorial_soup.append(editorial_article)

editorial_container_soup.append(editorial_soup)
editorial_container.append(editorial_container_soup)
print(editorial_container.prettify())
```

It does the job but I feel its too long. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the task that you are doing I would strongly consider using [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) template instead of BeautifulSoup.

If you used Jinja, you just need to pass a dictionary with the editorial information to a `editorial.html` that could look like this:

```
<!-- reusable editorial.html -->
<div class="editorial">
    <div class="editorial-title">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="editorial-image"><img src="{{ image }}"></div>
    <div class="editorial-subtitle">{{ subtitle }}</div>
    <div class="editorial-article">{{ article }}</div>
</div>
```

Include the `editorial.html` in the following html file, that will be loaded by flask. This will serve as your base template in this example.

```
<!-- template.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jinja Sample</title>
    </head>
<body>
    {% include "editorial.html" %} 
</body>
</html>
```

**Using Flask**

Start a flask app like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def editorial_test():
    editorial_info = {
        "title" : "Hello",
        "image" : "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/collie-border/n02106166_2595.jpg",
        "subtitle" : "world",
        "article" : "Yeah. But Parasite? It should have been Gone with the Wind!"
    }

    return render_template('template.html', editorial=editorial_info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I haven't tested the code above. Have a look at this excellent [tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/) for further clarification.

**Render files directly**

If you do not want to use Flask, you could render the webpage directly like this (Im assuming all files are in the same directory):

```
import jinja2

editorial_info = {
        "title" : "Hello",
        "image" : "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/collie-border/n02106166_2595.jpg",
        "subtitle" : "world",
        "article" : "Yeah. But Parasite? It should have been Gone with the Wind!"
    }

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "template.html"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
outputText = template.render(editorial_info) 

print(outputText)
```

*Output*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jinja Sample</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="editorial">
    <div class="editorial-title">Hello</div>
    <div class="editorial-image"><img src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/collie-border/n02106166_2595.jpg"></div>
    <div class="editorial-subtitle">world</div>
    <div class="editorial-article">Yeah. But Parasite? It should have been Gone with the Wind!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can, but it just feels wrong to do it this way because I don't need Flask at all in the project. I would want to wait for some other answers to decide my answer.

Comment: flask is just using jinja, you could just use the templating function without flask @jar

Comment: @jar,I've updated with an option to render the page directly. Using this option you can utilize the full power of Jinja and all its options.

Comment: Really appreciate your work. Got it working. I have even decided to use `Jinja2` and ditch `BeautifulSoup`. I have upvoted your solution, however I can't accept it as an answer. Accepting it as an answer will need me to fundamentally change the question which would then become totally different. I'd like for others to actually find this question if they are thinking of doing something similar using `BeautifulSoup`, and then realize that `Jinja2` is much better. I think we would be helping the community much more that way. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @jar I think most people would consider using BS to do this such an anti pattern that the answer - don’t use X, use Y is actually fairly acceptable.  It’s not like, oh, you are using Flask, don’t use it, use Django (or the more common TS answers to JS questions).  Any other answer around BS would be bad advice.

Comment: @jar Thank you for your feedback and up vote, it is of course up to whether or not to accept, however, while you do that, consider the following the following. If someone asks you: `What is *the best way to get a screw into a board* using pincers?`, wouldn't you rather focus on the import part of that question: `the best way to get a screw into a board` and tell them to use a screwdriver - that the might not know existed?

Comment: @jar Hey, btw, I did not intend to sound snarky.  You didn't know this category of tools like Jinja existed, so you adapted BS for your use.  While it is the wrong tool for what you are trying to do, your use of it was a bit novel to me as well.  I already use BS to alter html by deleting nodes via CSS and your techniques may yet come in handy to tweak some existing content.